# My HP ProBook 4530s got much hotter with Ubuntu Linux than Windows 7

Tags: linux, drivers, ubuntu-10.04, cooling, chipset

I have a [ProBook 4530S](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF06a/321957-321957-64295-3929941-3955552-5060880.html) with Windows 7 on it. I've got the software drivers [from here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=5060882&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5060880).

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 x64 on it. I am noticing that the notebook became **much hotter**, even after installing the ATI Driver (which I got from ATI website)

Are there any drivers that I need to install? (It's Intel 2<sup>nd</sup> Gen Core i5)

According to [the driver site from HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=5060882&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5060880&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=2020), there are not many drivers related to the chipset that I need to Install – just the ATI driver, which I already got from the ATI website, and the Intel VGA driver.

Here's the result of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc NI Seymour [AMD Radeon HD 6470M]
24:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
24:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
24:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 30)
25:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
26:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Is there anything missing?

Comment: I experience the same thing with my hp dv7 with an nvidia card.  I think it's a glitch with power management in the general driver...like it doesn't distinguish between desktop and laptop cards w/ and w/o on card fans.

Comment: Do you have any solutions for it? even workarounds?

Comment: at present, no...sorry.

Comment: i haven't tried it, but you might be able to hack something together with manually setting your main fan to a higher constant speed...

Comment: :S Can you point me to a place to start from?

Comment: acpi parameter manipulation seems the way to go...here's a brief discussion: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-66328.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same problem. Disabling discrete graphic from BIOS did the trick. Now the fan is regular.

I hope my answer is useful for someone that can work on discrete graphics integration with ubuntu, or help someone that is formatting just because having fan always running.

Comment: Why would someone remove your answer? It is a solution to the problem, not perfect but a solution.

Comment: It solved the problem, thanks. but I really miss the ATI card!